# Restore old Jenkins jobs in Windows after the update

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

We were running plug-in rich **Jenkins 2.46.1** and one of my team member tried to update Jenkins but it just hangs on displaying **Please wait while Jenkins is restarting** message for about 2 hours so I somehow forced Jenkins to shutdown and then started it using **java -jar Jenkins.war** command.

When Jenkins restarted again all my jobs were not displayed in Jenkins GUI but they were present in **jobs** and **workspace** folders so I tried an option **Reload configuration from disk** but that also did not restore jobs.

Please someone advice how I can restore my Jenkins jobs as they were before.

Comment: did you try to uninstall the plugin so you can go back to your old jenkins configuration?

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan No, I did not uninstall any plugin. My old Jenkins was plug-in rich and I just tried to update Jenkins but that did not happen. It just hanged.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not pointing JENKINS_HOME correctly. You may need something like this as startup script/batch file

For Linux:

```
export JENKINS_HOME=<path/to/old/jenkins/home>
java -jar Jenkins.war
```

For Windows:

```
set JENKINS_HOME=<path/to/old/jenkins/home>
java -jar Jenkins.war
```

Basically running war directly points to default temp directly for Jenkins Home. It can be overwritten by above environment variable. You can also centrally define it so that each start you do not need specify again.